# Add an offset to part of a list in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, scipy

I have a list `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, and now I wish to add a `1` to every element from `index 2` onwards, i.e. `a[2] + 1`, `a[3] + 1`, `a[4] + 1`.

That is I want `a = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]` in the end.

What is **the most Pythonic way** of dong so?

Comment: @aaronman it should skip the first two elements

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a[2:] = [x+1 for x in a[2:]]
>>> a
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

For numpy array:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> a[2:] += 1
>>> a
array([1, 2, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(2, len(a)) :
    a[i] += 1
```

Comment: If you are going to do it this way at least update in place: `a[i]+=1`.